Using inter font like usual suddenly produces an error in lgrenc.def and prohibits roman family
All of a sudden (for me), the usual font setup I use does not work anymore.
Not only does the line with inter produce the error

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inter/inter.sty
Package: inter 2023/11/23 (Carl-Clemens Ebinger & autoinst) Style file for inter fonts (Inter v.4.0)


(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package


! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `lgrenc.def' not found. (fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

but also prohibits serif font / roman font family from being typeset.
Is there a solution to this for the time being until it gets patched or is the setup now wrong (for whatever reason)?
Screenshot of MWE (problem)

Screenshot of MWE (with the line containing inter commented out)

MWE
\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV=15,
fontsize=10pt,
]
{scrreport}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
oldstyle,
]{sourceserifpro}
\usepackage[scale=1.02]{zi4}
\usepackage[scale=0.935]{inter}


\usepackage[
protrusion=true,
expansion,
babel=true,
%stretch=10,
%shrink=10,
tracking=true,
]{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{itemize}
    \item wordstuff 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \rmfamily A sentence to showcase the problem.
        \item \textrm{asdf}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}


works fine for me. Show your complete log-file (that means I get no error).

The error about lgrenc.def not being found means you have a bad installation of the TeX system. What TeX distribution are you using?

lgrenc.def is part of the the texlive greek-fontenc package but how it should be installed depends on the tex distribution you are using.

If you're on Linux, tell us which distro and which packages you installed to install TeX.

@egreg @cfr I am on Linux and using TL.
$ uname -r
6.8.7-arch1-2
$ pacman -Q texlive-core
texlive-basic 2024.2-1

@DavidCarlisle @Ulrike-Fischer Thank you for your comments. I installed texlive-langgreek. Now rmfamily produces sans font...  https://pastebin.com/V8DbnKAr https://imgur.com/EZrdC80 is there another package missing?

I can't see anything wrong with the image but you shouldn't be asking people to debug images. show the log file for your example. If you have missing files there will be errors or warnings. More generally you are using many uncommon fonts, which is fine but why not make it easy and install texlive-full rather than textlive-basic which is a minimal setup.  Then,for every document that fails,  have to ask here which packages you are missing?

the inter package  makes everything use that font so rmfamily is sans serif

@DavidCarlisle Well I took notice of the fonts at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/, documentation or not. However inter turning everything sans is entirely new to me. The MWE reflects how I had the font setup for years.

the package isn't really documented, the fact that it makes everything sans serif was just an observation looking at your example, not any prior knowledge of mine.

@DavidCarlisle Well I am incredibly surprised by the problem, I just never noticed it before. Thank you for your answer which solved it.

it's possible that the inter package (which uses non standard font shape names) is confused by some changes elsewhere and it wasn't intended to change the whole document to sans serif. (it does have options default and sfdefault and mainfont, but they didn't seem to do much and I didn't trace the code)

You are using largely undocumented font packages after installing a very minimal tex installation.
The inter package makes everything sans serif, the simplest thing here is probably just load it first then load the source serif pro package later to reset the \rmfamily

\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV=15,
fontsize=10pt,
]
{scrreport}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[sfdefault,scale=0.935]{inter}
\usepackage[
oldstyle,
]{sourceserifpro}
\usepackage[scale=1.02]{zi4}



\usepackage[
protrusion=true,
expansion,
babel=true,
%stretch=10,
%shrink=10,
tracking=true,
]{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{itemize}
    \item wordstuff 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \rmfamily A sentence to showcase the problem.
        \item \textrm{asdf}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

